# Drawing nices curves with periodic boundaries and without segments

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Using the library `pyephem`, I would like to find a way to do a nice plot (longitude, latitude) curves which represents the ground track of a satellite. I have computed the (longitude, latitude) but when longitude is over +180°, the next value computed is for example -178°, such that a segment is drawn, that makes bad figure.

Below the code that I have for the moment and the figure obtained.

```
currentDate = date.datetime(2018,12,1,0,0,0);

for i in range(nPoints):
  iss.compute(currentDate)
  # compute latitude
  posLat[i] = iss.sublat*(180/math.pi)
  # compute longitude
  posLong[i] = iss.sublong*(180/math.pi)
  currentDate = currentDate + date.timedelta(seconds = (time3orbits/nPoints*3600))                
  print currentDate, posLong[i], posLat[i]

plt.plot(posLong,posLat)
plt.show()
```

Here the figure that I get (for 3 orbits around earth):

[image]

How to prevent the segments drawn?

`iss.sublat` and `iss.sublong` are repectively the current latitude and longitude of iss position (from a `currentDate` fixed).

Comment: what is iss and iss.sublat?

Comment: maybe you want to sort the (lat,long) points by lat before plotting them?

Comment: @BanishedBot . Yes maybe but how to deal with longitude passing for example from 177° to -178° without drawing a segment between the 2 points ? you can see output data in **UPDATE 2**. Regards

Comment: plot() connects consecutive points by lines by default. maybe you want to use scatter() instead? not sure what your goal is or what you want the figure to look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the data array on sign changes from positive to negative and then plot the single sub-arrays:

```
orbits = np.argwhere(
    (data[:-1, 0] * data[1:, 0] < 0)
    & (data[1:, 0] < 0)
).ravel() + 1

for orbit in np.split(data, orbits, axis=0):
    plt.plot(orbit[:, 0], orbit[:, 1])
```

[image]